# Laravel queue with beanstalkd throwing RuntimeException (signal "11"?)

Tags: php, laravel, centos, beanstalkd, laravel-artisan

When pushing a job into the beanstalkd queue and beanstalkd start working it, it throws an error saying:

> [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]
>       The process has been signaled with signal "11".

/etc/syslog/beantstalkd:

```
# System configuration for the beanstalkd daemon

# Available options correspond to the options to the
# beanstalkd commandline.

BEANSTALKD_ADDR=0.0.0.0
BEANSTALKD_PORT=11300
BEANSTALKD_USER=beanstalkd

# Job size is left to the default. Uncomment and set it
# to a value to have it take affect.
#BEANSTALKD_MAX_JOB_SIZE=65535

# Using the binlog is off by default.
#
# The direcory to house the binlog.
BEANSTALKD_BINLOG_DIR=/var/log/beanstalkd/binlog
#
# fsync the binlog at most once every N milliseconds.
# setting this to 0 means 'always fsync'. If this is unset,
# and the binlog is used, then no explicit fsync is ever
# performed.  That is, the -F option is used.
#BEANSTALKD_BINLOG_FSYNC_PERIOD=
#
# The size of each binlog file.  This is rounded
# up to the nearest 512 byte boundary.
#BEANSTALKD_BINLOG_SIZE=10485760
```

What does

> The process has been signaled with signal "11".

exactly mean?

Comment: Are you running the `artisan queue:listen` command manually or are you using process control system such as `supervisord`?

Comment: I'm asking that because **signal 11** means **segmentation fault**, which can be caused by a lot of things. So establishing if you have an extra process in the mix, might help pinpoint the cause of the problem.

Comment: I ran the `artisan queue:listen` command after finding out that the supervisord process did not process the queue. So in an attempt to debug  I tried to run the process manually to look at the output. In short, the above output is from the manual command

Comment: Does the job run succesfully if you set your queue driver to `'default' => 'sync'` instead of `'default' => 'beanstalkd'` in `app/config/queue.php`?

Comment: Does the user you run the `queue:listen` command with, have the permissions needed for the job to execute successfully (ex: the necessary permissions to write data to disk if that's part of the job, etc) ?

Comment: I ran the queue:listen command as the root user. So it should have the necessary permissions right? I question though, the beanstalkd service is run as the beanstalk user. Does that user need to have any permissions I might not be aware of?

Comment: Have you been able to determine the cause of this issue?  I'm experiencing the same issue on redis.

Comment: I eventually worked it out, though I'm still not sure what the exact cause was. It's definitely a permission issue. After giving beanstalkd root permissions and changed ownership of logs it started working. A tip for debugging: write unit tests for queueing the jobs. I used the payload from the failed jobs as test data. It will give you some more specific error messages.